# pyportfolioopt: latest_prices should be a pd.Series with no NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I am trying to run the HRP Optimisation from pyportfolioopt pip package and I get the following error:

```
    File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 562, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/home/user/webapp/streamlit/pages/HRP Optimisation.py", line 46, in <module>
    da_hrp = DiscreteAllocation(cleaned_weights, df, total_portfolio_value=100000)
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pypfopt/discrete_allocation.py", line 71, in __init__
    raise TypeError("latest_prices should be a pd.Series with no NaNs")
```

What can I do? One thought was to convert NaN's to zeros but wouldnt that affect the result of the optimisation? Will the optimisation be accurate?

ANY help much appreciated

Comment: What about dropping the NaNs?

Comment: Hello @Alessandro Wouldn't that rows from other tickers? Thank you